# Hello Ј'ai this error after deploying my application, Key error

Tags: django, apache, deployment

Hello Ј'ai this error after deploying my application, I checked everything works locally for users on Django admin. I don't understand this mistake; Could you help me?

It looks like it's from the library in django admin and he says he doesn't know the value 1, so maybe it's a problem with this version of django; I would like to point out that I am using version 3.2.12 of django and that I am using a mysql database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Oj4.png)

Comment: Where do you see that "it doesn't know the value 1"? The linked error message shows a strange KeyError for 'False'.

Comment: I try to change the value in database for privileges , 1 seems is true and 0 is false ,

Comment: You try to edit the database manually? Which table?

Comment: yes with mysql et table authentification_user

Comment: In general that is not a good idea, because Django cannot apply validation rules. What did you change exactly?